# Help with this integration by parts boundary term

Tags: integration, vector-analysis

I have this in my notes:
$\int_\Omega{(\partial_i^2 u)(\partial_k^2 u)}
= \int_{\partial\Omega}{(\partial_i u)(\partial_k^2 u)\cdot n \mathbf{d}S} - \int_\Omega{(\partial_i u)(\partial_i \partial_k^2 u)}$
but I can't see how that boundary term becomes that. 
Can anyone tell me what theorem/result is used to get that?

(This is a line in the topic of elliptic regularity that I am doing atm, if that helps at all..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is a summation in the integral. For example, $\partial_i^2 u$ should be $\sum_{i=1}^n\partial_i^2 u=\Delta u$, and $\partial_k^2 u$ should be $\sum_{k=1}^n\partial_k^2 u=\Delta u$, etc. With this understanding, the formula you are asking should be
$$\int_\Omega(\Delta u)^2=\int_{\partial\Omega}(\Delta u)\nabla u\cdot n dS-\int_\Omega\nabla u\cdot\nabla(\Delta u).$$
To derive this, one can apply the divergence theorem to the vector field $X=(\Delta u)\nabla u$. That is:
$$\int_\Omega\nabla\cdot X=\int_{\partial\Omega}X\cdot ndS.$$
Then
$$LHS=\int_\Omega\nabla\cdot X=\int_\Omega\nabla\cdot ((\Delta u)\nabla u)=\int_\Omega\nabla u\cdot\nabla(\Delta u)+\int_\Omega(\Delta u)^2$$
because $\nabla\cdot\nabla u=\Delta u$.
On the other hand, 
$$RHS=\int_{\partial\Omega}X\cdot ndS=\int_{\partial\Omega}(\Delta u)\nabla u\cdot ndS.$$

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the late acceptance.

Comment: No problem. It's good that it helps.